# Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(38,)' not found

Tags: django

Full error:

> Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(38,)' not found.
>
> 1 pattern(s) tried:
>
> ['(?P[^/]+)/posts/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

models.py

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        content = models.TextField()
        date_published = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now)
        game = models.ForeignKey('library.Game', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        article_image = models.ImageField(default='/media/default.png', upload_to='article_pics')
        platform = models.CharField(default='PC', max_length=20)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.article_title

        class Meta:
            ordering = ["-date_published"]


        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    cover = models.ImageField()
    cover_display = models.ImageField(default='default.png')
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
class TitlePostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'main/title_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5


    def get_queryset(self):
        title = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return Post.objects.filter(game=title).order_by('-date_published')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TitlePostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return context

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

urls.py

```
 path('<str:title>/posts', TitlePostListView.as_view(), name='title-posts'),
 path('<str:title>/posts/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

I'm trying to make the path something like domain.com/Minecraft/posts/38 but I get an error probably because str:title is not defined. I'm not exactly sure how to go about adding it to my PostDetailView.

Edit:

post-detail.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/post_detail.css' %}">
{% endblock styles %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container black container-position">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="media content-section">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.article_title }}</h2>
                 <div class="article-content">{{ object.content|safe }}</div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Just for clarity, you want to pass 'title' as a parameter to PostDetailView, right?

Comment: Whatever I need to do to be able to use <str:title> in the url path.

Comment: Try using `self.kwargs['title']` in a method of PostDetailView. Note that you cannot use it as a class variable initialized at class instantiation.

Comment: Can you show the template from which this error is being generated?

Comment: The template? As in the post-detail.html? I just added that.

Comment: The error is being generated from `path('<str:title>/posts/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),` in the urls.py file

Comment: You need to edit the link of the detail view, which is present in your `main/title_posts.html`. Can you please add that html instead of post-detail html.

Comment: This is the link to the detail view `{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}`

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

you're missing the other required argument `title`, it should be something like:

```
return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'title': 'sometitle'})
```

Take a look to the pattern presented in the error:

> ['**(?P[^/]+)**/posts/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

In the first part you can see `(?P[^/]+)`  the plus sign (+) there means "at least one character" so the title is not allowed to be empty and you just have not defined an URL pattern for that case, hence the error.

Comment: I tried something like this `return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'title_id': self.game.pk})` but I'm still getting an error of `Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(38,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<title_id>[0-9]+)/posts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`